# Changing the stroke color for different sections in a nested loop

Tags: javascript, processing, nested-loops, p5.js

I've managed to create 3 'for' loops and assign each set a different color. I then decided to combine the 3 'for' loops into one nested loop to keep it concise, but I can't get the color (stoke of the lines) to change for each section (like I had when the loops were separate). I was wondering if anyone could help me add the color into the 1 nested loop.

I have the 3 separate `for`-loops so you can see how it is suppose to look. And I commented out the code that I want to include (the nested loop without the colors) in my final code.

```js
let wallx = 200;
let wally = 200;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 700);
}
function draw() {
    background(220);
    noLoop();

//This code combines the 3 'for' loops into a nested loop
// for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
//     for (let j = 0; j < (wally+1); j += (wally) / 20) {
//         strokeWeight(3);
//         (line(0*(i+wallx), j, (wallx*i), j));
//     }
// }

    for (let i = 0; i < (wally+1); i += (wally) / 20) {
        stroke(0, 0, 255);
        strokeWeight(3);
        (line(0, i, (wallx), i));
} 
    for (let j = 0; j < (wally+1); j += (wally) / 20) {
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        strokeWeight(3);
        (line(wally, j, (wallx*2), j));
}
    for (let k = 0; k < (wally+1); k += (wally) / 20) {
        stroke(0, 255, 0);
        strokeWeight(3);
        (line(wally*2, k, (wallx*3), k));
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array of colors

```js
let colors = [color(255, 0, 0), color(255, 255, 0), color(0, 0, 255)];
```

Set the `stroke` color dependent on `i`:

```js
stroke(colors[i]);
```

Fix drawing the line:

<s>`line(0*(i+wallx), j, (wallx*i), j);`</s>

```js
line(wally*i, j, (wallx*(i+1)), j);
```

```js
let wallx = 200;
let wally = 200;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 700);
}
function draw() {
    background(220);
    noLoop();

    let colors = [color(255, 0, 0), color(255, 255, 0), color(0, 0, 255)];
    for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < (wally+1); j += (wally) / 20) {
            stroke(colors[i]);
            strokeWeight(3);
            line(wally*i, j, (wallx*(i+1)), j);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```